# Set shell script Android SELinux policies for starting it at sys boot completed

Tags: android, shell, android-source, selinux

I am facing troubles for creating the SELinux policies for a sh script (init.myservice.sh) with the following content:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
/system/bin/am force-stop 'com.myapp.apptest'
/system/bin/tinymix 'Headphone Volume' 35;tinymix 'Capture Input' ADC;tinymix 'DMIC Mux' DMIC2;
/system/bin/am start -n ' com.myapp.apptest/ com.myapp.apptest.MainActivity' -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
/system/bin/my_board_service &
```

As you can see, this script does the following things:

- Stops (and starts) a APK application
- Sets few mic and audio settings with tinymix
- Starts a binary (my_board_service) which is a C++ compiled program which interacts with the custom board peripherals (GPIOs, I2C, etc...)

I've added into my "init.rc" file the following lines:

```
on property:sys.boot_completed=1
    start init-myservice

service init-myservice /system/bin/sh /system/bin/init.myservice.sh
    class main
    user root
    group root system
    disabled
    oneshot
```

I can see the script in the built system under the path "/system/bin" and the binary with the correct permissions (755) and if I launch it manually it works well. But I'm unable to launch it at system boot because (without any policies set) I get this error on the shell:

> Command 'start init-myservice' action=sys.boot_completed=1
> (/vendor/etc/init/hw/init.freescale.rc:334) took 5ms and failed: Could
> not start service: File /system/bin/init.myservice.sh(labeled
> "u:object_r:system_file:s0") has incorrect label or no domain
> transition from u:r:init:s0 to another SELinux domain defined. Have
> you configured your service correctly?
> https://source.android.com/security/selinux/device-policy#label_new_services_and_address_denials

So I'm trying to generate service policies without any luck. I've tried the following:
The content of my .te file is the following:

```
# foo service
type foo, domain;
type foo_exec, exec_type, file_type;
init_daemon_domain(foo)
```

I've added the following line in the "file_contexts" file under this location: "android_build/device/variscite/imx8m/dart_mx8mm/sepolicy/"

```
/system/bin/init\.myscript\.sh      u:object_r:foo_exec:s0
```

When I build my AOSP project I get few errors like this one:

> FAILED:
> out/target/product/dart_mx8mm/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_28.0_intermediates/treble_sepolicy_tests_28.0
> /bin/bash -c "(out/host/linux-x86/bin/treble_sepolicy_tests -l
> out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libsepolwrap.so  -f
> out/target/product/dart_mx8mm/obj/ETC/plat_file_contexts_intermediates/plat_file_contexts
> -f out/target/product/dart_mx8mm/obj/ETC/vendor_file_contexts_intermediates/vendor_file_contexts          -b out/target/product/dart_mx8mm/obj/ETC/built_plat_sepolicy_intermediates/built_plat_sepolicy
> -m out/target/product/dart_mx8mm/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_28.0_intermediates/28.0_mapping.combined.cil
> -o out/target/product/dart_mx8mm/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_28.0_intermediates/built_28.0_plat_sepolicy
> -p out/target/product/dart_mx8mm/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy
> -u out/target/product/dart_mx8mm/obj/ETC/built_plat_sepolicy_intermediates/base_plat_pub_policy.cil
> --fake-treble ) && (touch out/target/product/dart_mx8mm/obj/ETC/treble_sepolicy_tests_28.0_intermediates/treble_sepolicy_tests_28.0
> )" The following domain(s) must be associated with the "coredomain"
> attribute because they are executed off of /system: foo

Comment: https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate#using_audit2allow   to show what rules you are missing

Answer (score 0):

I recently was able to get what you are describing to work, but there were some differences in our approaches.  All of my changes were in "/vendor" on the target.  I'm not sure where your init.rc changes were going, but you described your script as being installed in "/system".

Otherwise most of what you are describing is familiar including having issues compiling the SELinux policy.  In the end the policy that worked for me looked something like this:

```
# foo service
type foo, domain;
type foo_exec, exec_type, vendor_file_type, file_type;

init_daemon_domain(foo)

# followed by all the particulars of my service.
```

If you are set on installing your service in "system" instead of "vendor", the wording of the error message seems to be telling you to associate your domain with the "coredomain".  I think that means your policy should include the following line somewhere before "init_daemon_domain":

```
typeattribute foo coredomain;
```

You should also be aware that I've seen it said that there is a SELinux policy that prohibits mixing "vendor" with "system".  I'm not sure, but I think it means that if you modified an init.rc in the /vendor file system to run your script, you are limited to using "stuff" found in the /vendor file system.  Your example above shows your script using /system/bin/sh, so if you modified an init.rc in the /vendor file system to start that script, I think that would be a violation.